# Pioneer DDJ-SB2 unbalanced sound

Tags: speakers

I recently purchased a pioneer DDJ-SB2 and  want to use it with some active Vonyx speakers which have both RCA and XLR inputs.

I'm not really much of an expert in the technical sound data (TS/TRS), so if I could get some help with my questions below, it would be a great help.

What are the pros and cons of the 3 options I have:

- 6 meter RCA cable, will I lose much sound quality?
- RCA to XLR cable
- RCA to XLR converter and an XLR cable

There would be only the power cables to the speakers near them.

Comment: RCA if you dont care about noise immunity and have a short cable run, or the Neutrik adapters and XLR cables if you want better noise immunity and/or have a long cable run.

Answer (score 1):

An RCA to XLR cable WILL NOT convert an unbalanced signal to balanced. It will simply convert a balanced cable to unbalanced and the signal will remain unbalanced for the entire length of the XLR. Consequently it will still be subject to interference from the mains cables in proximity. In order to balance the signal you will need a pair of balancing transformers or passive DI boxes.

Comment: Hi , thnaks for the replies , as most di boxes are 1/4 jack would it be ok if I used an adaptor from my RCA output to 1/4 jack , then used the 1/4 jack for the di box ? If not can you recommend a di box with RCA input . I've seen the cleanbox pro but seems quite hard to get hold of in UK

Comment: just get an RCA->Jack adapter and plug it into the DI Box. These are fairly cheap and discrete.